# Why am I getting Typeerror super expression must either be null or a function?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, components

So I just started learning React Native last week to try and learn to develop apps. I've been learning from a Udemy course and it has been going pretty well until I tried to create a new component. I've rewatched the lesson 3 times to try and find my mistake but I can't seem to see a difference between code. Please forgive my amateur mistake wherever it is. The main app.js file contains this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';
import Landing from './src/Landing'
import { render } from 'react-dom';

var myBackground = require('./assets/icons/landing.jpg');

export default class App extends React.Component() {
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Landing />
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0
  },
});
```

and my component code is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';

var myBackground = require('../assets/icons/landing.jpg');

class Landing extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } source={myBackground}>
                    <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Welcome to PokeSearch</Text>
                    <Button block={true} style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={()=>{}}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start Searching for Pokemon!</Text>
                    </Button>
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0
    },
    imgBackground: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      flex: 1 
  },
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    margin: 10
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'red'
  },
  });


export default Landing;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to find where I am going wrong...
Here is the full error in the emulator:
[image: error]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

change `export default class App extends React.Component()` to `export default class App extends React.Component`, you don't need parentheses in a class component.

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error but now I'm getting this error in the command line: Can't find variable: ImageBackground
* src\Landing.js:10:12 in render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13042:21 in finishClassComponent....

But I don't have imagebackground set as a variable, its just an image tag, so I'm unsure why it would be identifying as a variable...

Comment: you have not imported it in the Landing component. import it from the library (import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native')

Comment: @ShLuBsTeR, the errors might not always tell you specifically what happened as it is not easy for the React Library developers to guess all types of errors users would be making.

Comment: yes thank you I almost got it completely fixed now. The button and text is showing up now, just the background image isn't showing up. Sorry I'm a developer thats been out of practice for too long so I'm making stupid mistakes. I got laid off a year and a half ago and then I was having pc issues so I'm just starting to get back into developing

Comment: @ShLuBsTeR, do you have any errors in the console after adding ImageBackground import?

Comment: no errors at all despite me having the image background set as <ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } source={myBackground}>
But I don't think ill put alot of effort into fixing it, everything else seems to be working fine so I'll just continue with the tutorial, thanks for your help its appreciated!